# How to pass variable from Jade to .JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, pug

In my code below I have created an array of items in my .JS file. I was then able to pass this array to the .Jade and use each value in the array as an item in a dropdown list. I now want to pass the user input of which item they will click in the dropdown back to the server side (.js) so that I can use the user input to find more data.

My problem is that I don't know how to send the .jade variables to the server side. I want to send the "this.selectedIndex"/selected "val" so I can use it as a variable in the javascript file.

**.JS**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var projectPathArray = [];

  async function main() {                       
    var projects = await _db.listProjects();
        projects.forEach(async (item) => {
          var pathy = item.path;
          projectPathArray.push(pathy)
             })


res.render('index', { title: 'Projects', projectPathArray:projectPathArray}); 

}

main();
```

**.jade**

```
extends layout

script(src="libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

block content
  h1= title

  p To start, please select a project

  html
   body 
    form#test-form(action='', method='get')
    select#menu1(name='menu1', size=projectPathArray.length)
      each val in projectPathArray
        option=val
```

Comment: I think you need to back this whole thing up...I would add the route to handle `router.post` as well. Then change your `form#test-form`'s method to `post` and finally add a `submit` button. This way the user can submit the the form back into that `post` route handler where you can access `req.body` to see the value of `menu1`.

Comment: @EatatJoes Not looking for you fix my code entirely...but could you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: OK, I'll put in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without understanding exactly what you want this should at least get you closer to what you are asking for.

1) Add the route to handle the `post` where you can retrieve the values posted back in the form using `req.body`.

2) In your `Pug/Jade` template I indented the form elements so they are under the form, added a submit button, and changed the method of the form to `post`.

**.JS**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var projectPathArray = [];

  async function main() {                       
    var projects = await _db.listProjects();
        projects.forEach(async (item) => {
          var pathy = item.path;
          projectPathArray.push(pathy)
             })


res.render('index', { title: 'Projects', projectPathArray:projectPathArray}); 

});

main();
```

**.jade**

```
extends layout

script(src="libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

block content
  h1= title

  p To start, please select a project

  html
   body 
    form#test-form(action='', method='post')
                                      ^  
      select#menu1(name='menu1', size=projectPathArray.length)
        each val in projectPathArray
          option=val
      button(type='submit') Submit
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly to retrieve the data from the .jade file!! However what if I wanted to retrieve a specific variable, like the selected "val" in my example, without getting the whole "body".

Comment: Great, but `req.body` doesn't work that way...all form elements will be passed within `req.body`. What did `console.log(req.body.menu1)` print? It should show you the select element

Comment: Ohh yes, you're right. I don't have more to my jade script so I assumed that's the way it worked. It printed "{ menu1: 'firstvalueinarray' }. Thanks again, this will work fine!

Comment: Cool, just mark my answer as the answer and we are golden

Comment: Done! One last question... how can I use the req.body as a variable outside the parameters of the router.post function in order to use it within the rest of the .js file?

Comment: No, express's bodyparser will interpret the form only within the `.post()` route you created.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some mechanism for communicating from the frontend back to the server. This includes, but is not limited to, websockets and/or AJAX.